# How to change a radio button selection when a specfic input field in the form is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, radio-button

I need to be able to mark a radio button as checked when an input field is filled out (not empty). So when the "telephone number" field is filled out, the radio button should be immediately checked for SMS. Does anyone have an idea if this is possible?

```
<div class="form-group phone-field row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="inputPhone">Phone number (optional)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="prepend">+32</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phonenumber" id="inputPhone" placeholder="" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="switch-button row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="contact_style">Receive your token by</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="switch-field clearfix">
            <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="contact_style" value="email">
            <label for="switch_left">EMAIL</label>
            <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="contact_style" value="sms">
            <label for="switch_right">SMS</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is possible, have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an `event handler` for your `input` and then decide to check whether the radio has to be `checked` or not based on value is present or not. I have attached `input event handling` so that it identifies `copy/paste` too.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputPhone").on('input', function() {
    var val = $(this).val().length ? true : false; //check if it has value
    $('input:radio[value="sms"]').prop('checked', val);//check or uncheck
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group phone-field row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="inputPhone">Phone number (optional)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="prepend">+32</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phonenumber" id="inputPhone" placeholder="" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="switch-button row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="contact_style">Receive your token by</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="switch-field clearfix">
      <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="contact_style" value="email">
      <label for="switch_left">EMAIL</label>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="contact_style" value="sms">
      <label for="switch_right">SMS</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely plausible - but from a design side I would say just because I've entered a phone number doesn't mean I want my deliverables there ;)

Here's a working example using jQuery - it does not take into account validation because that's an entirely new issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/hepuu2kh/

```
$("#inputPhone").on('change', function(){
    var val = $("#inputPhone").val();
  if(val != ""){
        $("#switch_right").prop("checked", true)
  }
})
```

You can switch the event from 'change' to 'input' to have instantaneous updates when the textfield is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value of the input is not empty and set the radio button value:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#inputPhone').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      $('#switch_right').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#switch_right').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group phone-field row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="inputPhone">Phone number (optional)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="prepend">+32</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phonenumber" id="inputPhone" placeholder="" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="switch-button row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="contact_style">Receive your token by</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="switch-field clearfix">
            <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="contact_style" value="email">
            <label for="switch_left">EMAIL</label>
            <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="contact_style" value="sms">
            <label for="switch_right">SMS</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can't be simpler than this. I add so many event listeners.

```js
$('#inputPhone').on('input change keypress key down copy paste cut', function(e){
  $('#switch_right').prop('checked', ($(this).val()!=''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group phone-field row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="inputPhone">Phone number (optional)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="prepend">+32</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phonenumber" id="inputPhone" placeholder="" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="switch-button row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="contact_style">Receive your token by</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="switch-field clearfix">
            <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="contact_style" value="email">
            <label for="switch_left">EMAIL</label>
            <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="contact_style" value="sms">
            <label for="switch_right">SMS</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but you have to handle a an event that will do it.
I am believe a keyup event will suffice.

```
$("#inputPhone").keyup(function(){

 $("#switch_left").attr("checked", "checked");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code it will check the sms radio when we enter a phone number. we use "**onkeyup** to update the radio button.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
function radio(){

     $('#rad').attr("checked", "checked");
}  
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  Phone:<br>
  <input onkeyup="radio();" id="input" type="text" name="phone"><br>
  <input type="radio" id ="rad"  name="gender" value="sms"> SMS<br>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```